# Фильтрация объектов по придуманным атрибутам

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно фильтровать объекты по атрибутам, которые я прописал сам.  
Например, есть:

```
<div id='div'>11</div> и <div id='div'>11</div>
```

Через .attr (.attr("test","0(1)")) я прописал одному из них новый атрибут со значением 1, а второму - 0.  
Получилось:

```
<div test='1' id='div'>11</div> и <div test='0' id='div'>11</div>
```

Через .attr я могу посмотреть значения (1 и 0), но как мне выбрать блоки только со значением test='1'?

И подскажите, пожалуйста, ничего, если я использую свои названия атрибутов, а не те, которые свойственны DIV?

Comment: Попробуйте так http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: id не должны быть похожими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, у вас есть:

```
<div class="block">
  <div test="0" id='div0' class="div">11</div>
  <div test="1" id='div1' class="div">11</div>
  ...
</div>
```

чтоб выбрать только, те у кого test=1

```
$('.block').each(function () {
if($('div',this).attr('test')!=1)
$('div',this).css({'display':'none'}) //или можете удалить $('div',this).remove()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В 99.99% подобных случаев необходимости в изобретении своих атрибутов нет. Даже если бы существовал всего один атрибут **class**, то им вполне можно было бы обойтись, чтоб выделить элемент или группу из общей массы. Если всё-таки настаиваете, то:

```
$('[attr_name=some_val]').some_method();
```